# Parental Control - add program to restrict using C#

Tags: c#, security, block

I am looking for a way to restrict an application for a given user account (where user is a kid). I went through many question/answers on web and on stackoverflow as well but could not find anything. Any idea in this direction?
I am looking at following link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711682(v=vs.85).aspx

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Use credential based access to your application.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul.. Can it be done programatically? Say from C#? Any documentation link you have. I will though search it now on Google.

Comment: Yes, search for *Form based Authentication*

Comment: I think it is not what I want. I have a desktop application. Using this application, I want to restrict usage to certain installed programs. I want that when user tries to open those program, it present "Program is blocked dialog" which is similar to what you get when you enable parental control on an user account. If you see the link I shared, it works with low level WMI api and allows you to turn off/on parental control for given user account. But I want a way to add application in restricted program list. Something like adding full path to exe.

Comment: Use registry setting to block specified exe as described here http://www.howtogeek.com/180803/how-to-block-an-application-or-.exe-from-running-in-windows/

Comment: Kind of registry hack but sounds good to go to me for now. I think but I have to follow that approach in my program when switching user accounts. Wanted something that actually blocks for specific user. I will research in this direction though now.